# Get the Model context of a Key object in Datastore (App Engine)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'd like to bypass some frequent queries by storing `str(key)` in memcache. When I get the `encoded_key` back from memcached, I can reconstruct the key with `Key(encoded=encoded_key)`.

But how can I query the actual object from the key? A possibility would be to use

```
GqlQuery('SELECT * FROM ' + Key(encoded_key).kind() + \
    ' WHERE __key__ = ' + encoded_key)
```

but I'd rather not use GQL if possible. Is there a way of getting the object without using GQL?

Comment: As a side note, constructing GQL queries like this is a very bad idea. Parameters (:1, :2 etc) are provided to prevent the need to do this.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I know, this is just boilerplate code, I didn't want to use GQL in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you just storing the result of `str(key)` in memcached?  If so, when you get it back, you should be able to just do `db.get(key)` to get the entity to which it points.

`db.get()` will take either a `db.Key` object or the string representation of a `db.Key` object (or a list of keys or key strings).

Comment: Yay, thanks! I must have missed this useful piece of information while reading the API docs.